# Can't load images with short url

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a pygame (chrome dino game) in which I want the image of the dino. 
For that I put the image in the same folder as the code...
My code is:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load('main-character1.png')
```

But it shows error: FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
When I put the full path then only it works!

```
self.image = pygame.image.load('H:\CODING\Python\Games\Chrome Dino Game Python\main-character1.png')
```

Pls help I want to just write only small url not full...

THANK YOU...!

Comment: the same folder may not be the problem, maybe the current working directory?

Comment: make a folder with the name images put the image there and then load an image.

Comment: I did that also but still it did not work

Comment: check what is your current working directory . `import os    print(os.getcwd())`. if you pass filename only, without path, it will search for the file only in the  current working directory.

Comment: Put the image in the same folder of .py file.

Comment: The image is in the same folder...

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio CODE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this at the top of the script, make sure that the python file and the image is in the same directory

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
os.chdir(Path(__file__).parent)
```

Comment: I did not understand what are you trying to tell. Can you pls explain it clearly...

Comment: @AryaTholiya make sure the images are in the same folder as the python file

Comment: have you imported the os or the sys module?

Comment: The images are in the same folder as the python file...

Comment: @VedRathi No I did not import that I only imported pygame and random

Comment: So will I have to import that in order to make my code work?

Comment: let's see, do the following steps first ```import os``` then ```print(os.getcwd())``` and see what prints out

Comment: The output that you should be expecting is probably this H:\CODING\Python\Games\Chrome Dino Game Python\

Comment: Umm I dont think it is a long url...

Comment: The output is H:\CODING\Python

Comment: so that is the problem, ok, got it, I will update my answer, just wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229717/discussion-between-arya-tholiya-and-ved-rathi).